# Git: how to reset a working file to its index version?

Tags: git, indexing

The problem is the following: how to fetch a few files from a previous commit in git?

I could get the files one by one and replace them by their old version:

```
git show <commit>:<path>  >!  path
```

However, I would like to know whether there is a different way of performing the same thing, possibly with `git reset`.

In fact, I gather that

```
git reset <commit> <path>
```

puts the old  file into the index.  But how can the files in the index be moved back to the working tree?  Or is this a bad approach?

**PS**: There is a wonderful graphical explanation that makes everything clear: http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/.

Comment: You were looking for [`git reset --hard`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html). But `reset --hard` works on the whole tree - it can't back out change of a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put a file from a given revision into both the index and the working tree in one step, check it out:

```
git checkout <commit> <path>
```

If you've already put it only into the index, using `git reset <commit> <path>`, then no need to specify a commit:

```
git checkout <path>
```

That is, by default, `git checkout <path>` copies from index to work tree, but if provided a revision argument, it will copy from there into the index first.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the "git checkout" command? E.g.

```
git checkout master~2 Makefile
```

checks out the file (Makefile) from the older commit, which is what I understood you want to do. You'll then can decide if you want do add it to the index using "git add".

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with `git checkout HEAD~1 -- $FILENAME` to checkout the version previous to your last commit, replace `HEAD~1` by a rev-ID or a tag for other revisions.

---

**edit** there actually is [git-checkout-index](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html), so you could use `git checkout-index $FILENAME`.

---

**edit2** you may need to use the `-f` switch, i.e. `git checkout -f -- $FILENAME`. The `--` tells git you mean a file (only necessary if you have a branch or tag of the same name).

Comment: `git checkout <path>` (with no revision specified) checks out from the index anyway. `checkout-index` is more of a plumbing (lower-level) command.

Comment: Even though checkout-index is lower level, it's good to know about it.  Thanks!